# Exponent in a particular loop statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I'm newbie to JavaScript (and programming). I'm finding it hard getting my head round loops and how to apply them to real life situations... Can you please explain how does this statement below know to multiple 2 to the power of 10. I thought there would be a variable that puts "counter" and "result" together.

```
var result = 1; 
for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1) {    
    result = result * 2;     
    console.log(result);   
}  // → 1024

var result = 1;
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
    result = result * 2;
    counter = counter + 1;
}  
console.log(result); // → 1024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `for` and the `while` have conditions. In the `for` it continues through until `counter == 9` (starting at 0) so it does 10 loops. The `while` will continue to do everything inside the `{}` while the condition i.e. `counter < 10` is valid. In both cases they do something ten times. What they do in both cases is multiple the result by 2.

Comment: The key thing to bear in mind is that something will happen in the {}! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think what's confusing you is how the variable equals the variable like so: `result = result * 2`.

In the beginning of the script, `result = 1`. Inside the loop, `result` continues to multiply by 2. So in the first loop, `result = 1 * 2`. In the next loop, `result = 2 * 2`. In the third loop, `result = 4 * 2`, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Josan! You are right about what was confusing me. I have to remember that what happens inside the loop is supposed to happen 10 times.